# Removal of oil filter rotor lock nut and washer on 4 stroke

Tags: honda, motorcycle, oil, four-stroke

I am currently attempting a transmission repair on an old honda xl125 motor. I have been following the clives manual with very little issue.

However upon attempting to remove the clutch I am being instructed to remove the oil pump rotor. The corrosponding instruction being to:

***'remove the nut and lockwasher securing the oil rotor hosing in place'***

The issue being I cant actually figure out how to remove the nut and lock washer.

I have included a photo for reference.

Thanks.

[image]
[image]

Comment: [Would this method help you?](https://youtu.be/uSBIXNtwBgI) I realize it's for a 200, but it's the same basic thing.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this tool would do the trick: [link](https://www.ebay.com/itm/Honda-Oil-Pump-Filter-Clutch-Centre-Lock-Nut-Tool-XL-XR-125-185-200-350-HWT002/261359953477?hash=item3cda446645:g:MAkAAOSwr%7EhfWUYy)

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.